Advantage to jointly filing for bankruptcy when only one spouse has debt?
Is there an advantage to jointly filing for bankruptcy when only one spouse has debt?
When filing for taxes, there is almost always an advantage to filing jointly.

From the fairly little I know of US finance, an answer may depend on which state the parties are in, and whether that is a communal property state.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a question to ask your friendly neighborhood bankruptcy attorney.

Interesting parlance.  The word "advantage" and "bankruptcy" being used in the same sentence.

@Geremia II it legal to file for bankruptcy if you are married and your spouse is not? You  may want to ask that question on law stack exchange.
